# Change to cursor:default on players with is-inactive class, only after others selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

## Objective

- I have a list of sixty hockey players that all have a
  `is-inactive` with `cursor:pointer` as their **default state.** The div being referenced is **`<div class="picked is-inactive">`**
- When a player gets clicked on, it's "starred" and its class switches 
  to `is-active`. There are a maximum number of players in each position (two goalies, six defensemen, twelve forwards).
- When that max number has been reached, the remaining players in that 
  position that haven't been chosen / clicked on, should have `cursor: default` behaviour.

## Problem

Right now, even after the maximum number of players in a position have been selected, even the players that were not clicked and have the `is-inactive` state still have the `cursor:pointer` behaviour.

### scripts.js

```
    /*-------------------------------------
    COUNT SELECTED
    --------------------------------------*/

    function countSelected() {
        $(".player").on("click", function(){

            // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
            // If so, return false and then do nothing
            // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
            if ($(this).find(".picked.full").length > 0) return false;
            $(this).find(".picked").toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");

            // Count the number of players with stars
            var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-active").length;

            console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

            // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
            var maxGoaltenders = 2;
            var maxDefencemen = 6;
            var maxFowards = 12;

            // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
                $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".btn--submit").show();
                $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
            }
        });
} countSelected();
```

### style.css

```
.player {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

### index.html

```
<div class="player player--goalie year--1990">
                    <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
                        <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
                        <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
                            <div class="stats__group stats--games">
                                <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
                                <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
                                <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
                                <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
                    </div> <!-- tooltip -->
                    <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
                        <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
                    <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Answers take some effort. A comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your players always have the `is-inactive` class and you defined inside your `is-inactive` class the `cursor: pointer` property, they will always going to have the `cursor: pointer` thingy enabled. You have some options:

- Remove the `is-inactive` class from players that do not need to have the cursor.
- Creating an special class named F.E. `pointercursor` with only the `cursor: pointer` property, and add and remove that class when needed. (Obviously removing the property from your `is-inactive` class.
- I see that when full, you add the `full` class. You can add the `cursor: default` property to that class, to override the other property. Notice that for this class override the old one, it must be declared after the first one in your CSS file:

  ```
  .is-inactive {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .full { // This way, `full` will override `is-active`.
    cursor: default;
  }
  ```